# How to bind images to image control dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, dynamic

yes I know...and yes I did google that. The problem is I am very new to ASP.NET and none of the search results did match my requirements.

I have this:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgView" runat="server" />
```

In my database I have stored images and I can retrieve them by the following method:

```
public static List<Image> GetRezeptImages(int rezeptId)
{
    using (CookBookDataContext ctx = new CookBookDataContext(Resources.ResourceFile.DBConnection))
    {
        IEnumerable<RezeptBilder> bilder = from b in ctx.RezeptBilders where b.FKRezept == rezeptId select b;
        List<Image> imageList = new List<Image>();

        foreach (RezeptBilder b in bilder)
        {
            imageList.Add(Helper.ByteArrayToImage(b.Bild.ToArray()));
        }

        return imageList;
    }
}
```

Very important, as I started out with a Winforms application which I now want to turn into a ASP website, `Image` is from `System.Drawing.Image` not the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image`. I also have the possibility to convert my Images to byte arrays and vice versa:

```
public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
    {
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
}
```

Now if a certain event is triggred an `System.Drawing.Image` is fetched from the database and I want to display it in the image control. Here I need an Image-Url and therefor I have to save my image to the server. Which I can not do because it is not `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image`. I could convert it to a byte array but what then?

What would be the most suave way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help

```
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();


image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
  Response.ClearContent();
  Response.ContentType = "image/Gif";
  Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());


<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/pic.aspx"/>
```

Comment: Thank you but like I said I can not call Save on my Images because they or of type System.Drawing.Image

Comment: Why not? System.Drawing.Image objects have Save method. See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok so this actually does work, thank you so far. But instead of displaying the image in the Image-Control one redirected to another page where only the image is displayed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can display binary image using base64 string. Something like-

```
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
```

You can get more details on this link with demo link-

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-image-from-database-in-Image-control-without-using-Generic-Handler-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: This actually makes sense but I can't get it to work. Everything works fine, the Url gets assigned but it never shows the image.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this, I might work, worked for me.

```
  public class ImageToSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Image image = value as Image;
        if (image != null)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.StreamSource = ms;
            bi.EndInit();
            return bi;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and  create Propertey

```
public Image UserImage
{
    get
        {
            return _model.UserImage;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How did you generate byte[]? It works fine-

```
string id = "1";
byte[] bytes = (byte[])GetData("SELECT Data FROM tblFiles WHERE Id =" + id).Rows[0]["Data"];
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;


private DataTable GetData(string query)
{
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
```